# Memcached Kubernetes Client Golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, memcached, kube-dns

I am attempting to connect to my memcached instance via golang.  Both my app and Memcached will be in Kubernetes.

I couldn't find a good way (or example) on how to dynamically discover memcached and ensure that it will update if the pods scale.

I can manually create a client with the IP but not sure the best way to dynamically create clients in K8s with Golang.  Any help would be appreciated, below is my test function that I am using (if it helps).

```
func TestMemcached(t *testing.T) {
    mc := memcache.New("10.40.1.18:11211", "10.40.2.16:11211")
    mc.Set(&memcache.Item{Key: "foo", Value: []byte("my value"), Expiration: 1})

    it, err := mc.Get("foo")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("Error pulling from cache:" + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Key: " + string(it.Key) + "Value: " + string(it.Value))
    //Sleep for a second and a half to let the key expire
    time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
    it, err = mc.Get("foo")
    if err == nil {
        t.Error("Got a hit when I didn't expect it:" + err.Error())
    }
}
```

kubectl describe svc memcached:

```
Name:              memcached
Namespace:         redfalcon
Labels:            app=memcached
                   chart=memcached-2.3.1
                   heritage=Tiller
                   release=memcached
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=memcached
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              memcache  11211/TCP
TargetPort:        memcache/TCP
Endpoints:         10.40.1.23:11211,10.40.2.24:11211
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your memcache instance(s) as a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ in Kubernetes.

This way in the client you only specify the internal DNS entry for your service which would be something like `<service-name>.<k8s-namespace>.svc.cluster.local`.

In your code you would need something like this:

```
mc := memcache.New("memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local:11211")
```

You can also use [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) to specify this configuration for your application.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this but didn't work.

mc := memcache.New("memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local")
mc.Set(&memcache.Item{Key: "foo", Value: []byte("my value"), Expiration: 1})

I get "memcache: no servers configured or available"

Not sure why

Comment: Did you create a Kubernetes Service for your memcache deployment?

Comment: yes, called "memcached".   It is a statefulset so it is headless (if that matters)

Comment: Try to shell into another pod, and `ping memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local` see if that resolves. Try within the namespace and then another namespace. This is to check if DNS is working in your cluster

Comment: yeah, I checked that and it works.  Used nslookup and it resolved the ip address.

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.40.2.24
Name: memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.40.1.23
Name: memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.40.2.24
Name: memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.40.1.23

Comment: Does your service expose port `11211`? Also, is memcache listening and working on that port?

Comment: Yes and yes.   It works fine if I put in the IP address.

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl describe svc <memcache-service-name`?

Comment: Yes, posted to original

Comment: so you are missing the port, updated the answer. Basically, something like this: `mc := memcache.New("memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local:11211")`

Comment: Hmm, no love yet.   Something must be misconfigured somewhere in my service.

Comment: Can you run `telnet memcached.redfalcon.svc.cluster.local 11211` from the pod where you are running your Go code? If you get a connection then it's a client issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out!   It had to do with telepresence (https://www.telepresence.io/) that I am using for local development.  It gives me access to all K8s resources from my developmnet environment.   Unfortunately there is a defect in Linux where it cannot use K8s FQDN for lookup.

https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/161

Fixing is is sort of a hack, I port forwarded my K8s pod and when running in local development mode I changed my URL to "localhost:port".   This worked but it isn't really testing Memcached as K8s would use it.

When I deploy into K8s it works fine.